# CSS : How to add an absolute div to a scrollable background?

Tags: html, css, scrollview, absolute

I would like to add a div to a scrollable background, you may find the script I have for now [here](https://jsfiddle.net/783xjudm/).

I have a problem because when I add a box, it's being drawn to the window canvas, but I would actually like to draw it to the background `#wrapper`, and stay in the exact spot where the div is being added. 

For instance, if I do a click in a certain position (eg. images[0]), it will be drawn around the top right corner. However, when I started scrolling the background, the added div will stay in the same position. I would like the div to only be drawn at where images[0] is, and so if I start scrolling, it will still only be drawn at the position of images[0].

In the css, I tried to do that with assigning the width to 100% to the `#wrapper` as below, but it still doesn't work...

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hence, I would also like to know if it is a problem in my JS or CSS...

Thank you :)))

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: you're adding the blocks with a fixed position, so they're not moving with it. Add position relative to your wrapper and position absolute to your boxes (https://jsfiddle.net/783xjudm/3/) EDIT:wrong link

Comment: @LordNeo He just missed a relative parent div

Comment: @DavidChelliah fixed position is fixed to the viewport, not the parent, so only making the parent relative will not fix the issue, he also needs to set the boxes as absolute (to the parent).

Comment: @LordNeo I don't see him using `position:fixed` anywhere in his jsFiddle

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for everyone's answers :))) However, when I try to click in where images[0], images[1], or images[2], the box would appear in where the column of images[12] is (which is the border of the window canvas). I have also tried changing the value of width to be static but it doesn't work as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place absolute div(s), make sure you are placing it within a parent whose position is set to as **relative**. So that you can ***reliably control the position*** of your absolute child divs.

There is no issue with your Javascript.

Simply Set `position:relative`  to your `#wrapper` div. Everything should work as expected.

*See this fiddle*: 
https://jsfiddle.net/davidsekar/38ebkd05/

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for everyone's answers :))) However, when I try to click in where images[0], images[1], or images[2], the box would appear in where the column of images[12] is (which is the border of the window canvas). I have also tried changing the value of width to be static but it doesn't work as well...

Answer (score 1):

Adding `position: relative` to a scrollable element will fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what was already pointed (set the wrapper to relative), you need also to set the boxes as absolute:

jsfiddle.net/783xjudm/3

This will make the boxes stay absolute to the first relative parent (the wrapper) and not fixed in the viewport or absolute to the body.